# background-color with gradient transparent

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have the following html that have a div with a background color that came from the db

```
<div class="period" style="background-color: <%= color %>">
    <div class="day available">
        <div> 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the div with class "day available" I want to apply a gradient that will have 25% of transparent and 75% of green, so I can continue to view the period color and also see the availability.

I have this css for the class

```
.day{
    &.available{
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, $available 0%, $available 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 76%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* w3c */
    }
}
```

With this I have the gradient displayed, but I can't see the blue in the transparent section

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of the $available variable?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: $available: #BDF4BA;